# rails 3 routes new :new action singular form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I don't know if I'm being nit-picky with this one but how do you create a :new action member?

When I have

```
resources :posts, :except => [:show] do
  get :another_new, :on => :collection
end
```

this gives me a plural one (in routes `another_new_posts GET /posts/another_new(.:format)`).

But when I use member, I do get singular but it wants an :id (in routes `another_new_post GET /posts/:id/another_new(.:format)`).

How do I create another new which would say in routes as `another_new_post` with `/posts/new`?

Answer (score 0):

Place this as a standalone piece outside of your resources block:

```
match 'posts/another_new' => "posts#new", as: :another_new_post
```

Comment: Adding an :as only changes the name (:another_new). In this case, it gave me `another_new_post_posts GET /posts/another_new(.:format)`

Comment: The second solution will not have that problem.

Comment: True. But I was wondering if there is a way to do it within this kind of format instead of using match. I'll wait for a few more answers but if there is none and this is the only way, I'll mark this as the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: controller :posts do get 'another_new' => action: new, as: :another_new_post end

Comment: Really any of the routing methods besides resources would work just fine for you...

Comment: I'm actually not changing the :new of :posts but I'm adding a different one so I can't override it.

Comment: I'm not telling you to override anything. You can have more than one route point to the same action, and that's assuming you're even looking to have it go to the same method which you may not be. I'm just giving you the syntax for the general thing you're trying to do.